# remove item object javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I have the following object:

```
[{
    "id": 2,
    "price": 2000,
    "name": "Mr Robot T1",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/270x335"
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "price": 1000,
    "name": "Mr Robot T2",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/270x335"
}]
```

and what I want is to remove the first item (id = 1) and the result is:

```
[{
    "id": 2,
    "price": 2000,
    "name": "Mr Robot T1",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/270x335"
}]
```

as it could do?

Comment: Go to MDN and read about Array.prototype. Don't run to stackoverflow asking such basic questions. Also this has *nothing* to do with jquery.

Comment: You have an array of objects, not just an object.  You are asking to remove one indexed item in an array.  See: [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: Bonsoir Elliot : `array.splice(0,1)`

Comment: @mayken I'll try that function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following code?

```
var array = [{
    "id": 2,
    "price": 2000,
    "name": "Mr Robot T1",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/270x335"
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "price": 1000,
    "name": "Mr Robot T2",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/270x335"
}];

var newArray = [];

array.forEach(function(item){
    if (item.id != 1) {
        newArray.push(item);
    }
});
```

Basically that will loop through your array and all elements that don't have an `id = 1` will get pushed to the variable `newArray`.

**EDIT**

In order to delete the item you can always [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) it. Something like the following.

```
var array = [{
    "id": 2,
    "price": 2000,
    "name": "Mr Robot T1",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/270x335"
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "price": 1000,
    "name": "Mr Robot T2",
    "image": "http://placehold.it/270x335"
}];

array.forEach(function(item, index){
    if (item.id == 1) {
        array.splice(index, 1);
    }
});
```

Comment: yes, I understand that logic ... but tried to find some function to delete the item, rather than create a new one

Comment: thanks for the help, it is clear to me now :)

Comment: @funktasmas No problem! Glad I could help! Remember to accept the answer if it helped so it can help others also. Glad I could help tho.